# Undefined Object method

Tags: javascript

I have this code and as i use the `display` method it keeps giving me:

**url is undefined**

**name is undefined**

**description is undefined**

I don't know why i'm getting errors even though I am providing it will all the proprieties. Can somebody please identify the problem for me?

```
function website(name,url,description)
{
    //Proparties
    this.name=name;
    this.url=url;
    this.description=description;

    // Methods
    this.getName=getName;
    this.getUrl=getUrl;
    this.getDescription=getDescription;
    this.display=display;

    // GetName Method
    function getName(name)
    {
        this.getName=name;
    }

    // GetUrl Method
    function getUrl(url){
        this.getUrl=url;
    }

    // getDescription
    function getDescription(description){
        this.getDescription=description;
    }

    function display(name,url,description){
        alert("URL is :" +url +" Name Is :"+name+" description is: "+description);
    }
}

// Set Object Proparites
web=new website("mywebsite","http://www.mywebsite.com","my nice website");

// Call Methods
var name = web.getName("mywebsite");
var url = web.getUrl("http://www.mywebsite.com");
var description = web.getDescription("my nice website");
web.display(name,url,description);
```

Comment: declare variables before using them

Comment: Your `getX` functions actually are setters and return nothing?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getter functions are setters that overwrite themselves (?). Change them to

```
function getName(){
    return this.name;
}
function getUrl(){
    return this.url;
}
function getDescription(){
    return this.description;
}
```

and

```
function setName(name){
    this.name = name;
}
function setUrl(url){
    this.url = url;
}
function setDescription(description){
    this.description = description;
}
```

If you want your setters to return the set value, add `return` keywords before the assignments.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're pretty confused about how functions work. In your code you have:

```
this.getName=getName; // this sets a "getName" method on the "this" object
// to be some function that will be implemented below

function getName(name) // i believe this function shouldn't have any parameter...
{
this.getName=name; //now, you're overriding the "getName" that you set above,
// to be something completely different: the parameter you sent when calling this function!
// instead, you should do:
return name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You wanted to write this? :

```
function setName(name)
{
    this.name=name;
}
```

As I understood, you are setting, not getting properties. So:

```
var name = web.setName("mywebsite");
```

Answer (score 1):

I should declare it as

```
function () {
  //property
  this.name

  //method
  this.setName = function ( name ) {
  this.name = name
  }
}
```

They way your implementing it, asks for context problems

Answer (score 1):

Your getters should return a value instead of reassigning the getter itself e.g.

```
function getName() {
  return this.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should made return for the value as the following on each method:

```
// GetName Method
function getName() {
    return this.getName = name;
}

// GetUrl Method
function getUrl() {
    return this.getUrl = url;
}

// GetDescription Method
function getDescription() {
    return this.getDescription = description;
}
```